# Powershell misinterprets perl -M flag

Tags: powershell, perl

I am running Strawberry perl on Windows 10 from either Powershell or the CMD prompt. With CMD, you can change perl's available features on the command line with the `-M` option, followed by a version number, like this (to enable 'say', for example):

```
D:\>echo hello world |perl -M5.20.0  -ne "chomp; s/ll/rr/; say"
herro world

D:\>
```

With Powershell, the `-M` option eats the initial version number and looks for a script following it:

```
PS D:\> echo "hello world" |perl -M5.20.0  -ne "s/ll/rr/; say"
Can't open perl script ".20.0": No such file or directory
PS D:\>
```

The CMD behaviour is what I would expect and is also what bash gives me.

Why is Powershell different and how can I use the `-M<version#>` feature in Powershell?

Comment: I have found that putting double quotes around the "5.20.0" allows Powershell to pass the correct parameter on to perl. It remains a mystery to me why this should be the case.

Comment: Because PowerShell is a strange beast, neither fish nor fowl.

Comment: I assume `.` is a special character in powershell syntax.

Comment: It is an - unfortunate and long-standing - PowerShell bug you're seeing and there are several workarounds: the simplest is to `\``-escape the `-`; alternatively, use quoting. See the linked duplicate for details.

Comment: In this case, you could also use `perl -ne"use v5.20; s/ll/rr/; say"`.

Comment: @ikegami, I could, but I wanted to avoid putting the "use v5.20" inside the main loop.

Comment: Like, for performance? Doesn't matter. It has a compile-time effect. It's non-existent at run-time.